# Digital Ocean Hosting for personal development

Tags: magento2, hosting

I'm currently hosting my personal development on DO.  My droplet is 1CPU 2GB and 50GB storage.  I'm having issues with load times, mind you this is only for development, so I wouldn't even mind 3-4 second page loads. After I'm deep into a few pages, it just gets stuck, almost like its run out of memory.

My question is to anybody that has this same droplet / type of hosting plan.  Do you have issues as well? Also, new here, finally made the plunge, 10 years later! SMH

Thanks!

Comment: I had this issue only with this smaller droplet, on this one I have few stores and no issues. Like Herve said check logs and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are:

- verify the cache are all enabled (or since it is dev envrionment only a couple may be disabled)
- second, I would advise to use redis as it would not reload everything at every page load
- finally, you may check error logs